# SQL issue: Get Previous data based on a action code

Tags: sql-server, join, crystal-reports, inner-join, outer-join

I am stuck with this issue.
Please refer to screenshot too for table structure.

[SQL ISSUE SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMlaA.png)

So we have 2 tables : HISTORY table keeps histiry of payrate, location etc
& POSITION table only gives details of Job action changes datewise.
*Desired output* we want to only consider Action_code as 'JOB-CHANGE' and get the latest payrate and previous payrate before the action- job change.

--- table1: HISTORY ---

| EMPLOYEE | EFFECT_DATE | END_DATE | PAY_RATE | LOCAT_CODE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 344 | 4/1/2021 | current - TBD | 42.44 | ATL |
| 344 | 3/2/2021 | 3/31/2021 | 41.81 | ATL |
| 344 | 3/31/2020 | 3/1/2021 | 41.81 | DTW |

--- table2 ACTION ---

| COMPANY | EMPLOYEE | EFFECT_DATE | ACTION_CODE | REASON_01 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 344 | 3/31/2021 | LOA | ST-RTW |
| 100 | 344 | 3/2/2021 | JOB CHANGE | JC-TRANS(L |
| 100 | 344 | 5/31/2020 | LOA | ST-COVID90 |

--- DESIRED OUTPUT --

| Employee | Action code | Reason_1 | Effective_Date | Previous_Location | Previous_Rate | New_Location | New_Pay_Rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 344 | JOB CHANGE | JC-TRANS(L | 3/2/2021 | DTW | 41.81 | ATL | 42.44 |

Could you please help me out here. Thanks much :) in advance

Comment: How do you propose to join these two tables, what are the common columns, unclear? And what have you tried so far

Comment: Common columns are Action code, dates, payrates. pretty much everything. The tricky part is to consider only the action code-JOB CHANGE and get max and one level down payrates like its shown in desired output

Comment: That's not complicated: just a simple `LEAD/LAG`. The difficult bit is how do you want to match the rows. The only common columns I see are `EMPLOYEE, EFFECT_DATE`. If you match on those two, is the date with a time component, then do we do an exact match? Or do we get the first row on or before that date from the `history` table? And how is `New_Pay_Rate: 42.44` worked out, I don't get the logic

Comment: Okay yes, then we should join by EMPLOYEE. We want to consider Effect date of action. In  ACTION the job change happens on 03/02/2021 so we want to check what was the payrate and location before the JOB CHANGE happened and what is the pay rate and location after that (which becomes NEW pay rate and NEW location)

Comment: So whats bugging me is... if we consider DTW as previous location then new pay rate will still be be the 41.81 cz in second line of HISTORY table... new location is already captured as ATL with the same 41.81 rate...

Comment: Again, we can solve that with window functions, which I will show you. One further point: row 2 in `history` is exactly the same date. So do you then want the first row *on or before* the date in `action`? Or do these dates have a time component and therefore this is not relevant?

Comment: Oh okay sure Thanks. and yes We want the first row on the effective date of ACTION_CODE column which has 'JOB CHANGE' action.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP (1)` to get the first matching row on or before the date.

Within the `APPLY` you can use `LEAD` to access the values on the next row going backwards.

```
SELECT
  a.EMPLOYEE,
  [Action code] = h.ACTION_CODE,
  a.REASON_01,
  Effective_Date = a.EFFECT_DATE,
  hPrev.Previous_Location,
  hPrev.Previous_Rate,
  hNew.New_Location,
  hNew.New_Pay_Rate
FROM ACTION a
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP (1)
      Previous_Location = h.LOCAT_CODE,
      Previous_Rate = h.PAY_RATE
    FROM HISTORY h
    WHERE h.EFFECT_DATE < a.EFFECT_DATE
      AND h.Employee = a.Employee
    ORDER BY h.EFFECT_DATE DESC
) hPrev
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP (1)
      New_Location = h.LOCAT_CODE,
      New_Pay_Rate = h.PAY_RATE,
    FROM HISTORY h
    WHERE h.EFFECT_DATE > a.EFFECT_DATE
      AND h.Employee = a.Employee
    ORDER BY h.EFFECT_DATE
) hNew
WHERE a.ACTION_CODE = 'JOB CHANGE';
```

Comment: Ohkay lemme try that in DB, Thanks very much, I will let you know soon how it goes

Comment: Its for MS SQL? cz its not binding properly. I am getting error : Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near '.'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 20
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.

Comment: Sorry missing commas

Comment: Gotcha, il add them

Comment: Hii, so in the output the 'New_Pay rate' is still coming as 41.81. Its not coming as 42.44

Comment: OK change of plan, I think it's probably easier to go for two `APPLY`s, one for previous and one for new

Comment: Now its giving 'Previous_Locattion' as ATL. we want DTW cz before JOB CHANGE action it was DTW

Comment: Hi @Charlieface

Comment: Perhaps change `<=` to `<` (as edited now)